# Developing Sharepoint webparts in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, sharepoint, add-in

I want to use Visual Studio to develop webparts for Sharepoint. I've already got a source code that contains different .vue applications and a website which already uses most of those webparts.

I'm fairly new to SharePoint, so there's a few things I don't understand.

- In site contents, can I get the source code of the lists, apps etc. that are there?`
- How can I use the .vue applications/files from Visual Studio in the Sharepoint application?
- I created a new SharePoint-Add-In project in Visual Studio and connected it with the homepage of the website, but how can I work with the source code I have right now to deploy it to the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint 2013/2016, you could check [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254141/sharepoint-2013-on-premise-vuejs) for demos(SharePoint add-in with VUEjs).

If you're using SharePoint 2019/online, you could create SPFx solution so you could migrate vuejs by [PnP/generator-SPFx](https://pnp.github.io/generator-spfx/features/)

[SharePoint Framework(SPFx)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)